# Deleting all rows NOT selected by SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-delete

I have a table that lists Supplies and their Inventory Departments...A single supply can have multiple inventory departments so their will be multiple rows with the same supply yet different departments (some have multiples other do not) I have a script to select all of the supplies I DO NOT want to delete.

```
SELECT supply_num, 
       Min(tisclient_num)               AS tisclient_num, 
       Min(invdept_num)                 AS invdept_num, 
       Min(usage_freq)                  AS usage_freq, 
       Min(qty_on_hand)                 AS qty_on_hand, 
       Min(min_level)                   AS min, 
       Min(max_level)                   AS max, 
       Min(primary_supply_location_num) AS location, 
       Min(par_level)                   AS par 
FROM   mm_supply_tisclient_invdept 
GROUP  BY supply_num;
```

How can I delete everything from this table that is not selected within this select statement?

Comment: You can use the query you wrote as a subquery and delete from your table using NOT IN

Comment: With all of those `MIN`s in there - there's no guarantee that any or all of them come from one original row. So it wouldn't be a matter of just selective deletes, but possible a combination of UPDATEs and DELETEs - to the point where you may want to dump this data elsewhere, clear the table, then reimport this data, if it's meant to be the complete set of rows for that table.

Comment: I think Jack is correct; however considering the above query is returning multiple columns, wouldn't NOT EXISTS be more appropriate?  I don't think you can do a NOT IN against the query as is; it should return an error.

Comment: I guess all the columns are redundant and OP has added them just to be able to output a record with the `GROUP BY` without error. But it's not clear how he determines a duplicate, is it `supply_num` alone, is it where `invdept_num > 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `delete from TABLE_NAME where FIELD not in (select ... )` ?